# First project for Next.js deploying to Heroku, start script crashing?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, next.js

Any help for a newbie? This is my first next.js project in works fine on local with no warnings and passes deployment in heroku. But when i view app i get a error page to view my logs.

The tutorial that i was following was posted here https://medium.com/@jacoboakley/deploy-a-next-js-app-on-heroku-69bcb01db1b7

also have a git repo https://github.com/Narrabeen010/fifa-signup

Here is the output of my log:

```
    2020-05-03T09:35:57.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user user@gmail.com
2020-05-03T09:36:39.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user user@gmail.com
2020-05-03T09:36:56.583782+00:00 app[api]: Release v7 created by user user@gmail.com
2020-05-03T09:36:56.583782+00:00 app[api]: Deploy fa8f626a by user user@gmail.com
2020-05-03T09:36:56.828593+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-03T09:36:59.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-05-03T09:37:01.476773+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-03T09:37:02.046480+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-05-03T09:37:02.050475+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-03T09:37:01.934341+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-03T09:37:01.934359+00:00 app[web.1]: > donut-shop@1.0.0 start /app
2020-05-03T09:37:01.934359+00:00 app[web.1]: > next start -p $PORT
2020-05-03T09:37:01.934359+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-03T09:37:01.940598+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: next: not found
2020-05-03T09:37:01.945759+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-05-03T09:37:01.946029+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2020-05-03T09:37:01.946248+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2020-05-03T09:37:01.946512+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2020-05-03T09:37:01.947788+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! donut-shop@1.0.0 start: `next start -p $PORT`
2020-05-03T09:37:01.947905+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2020-05-03T09:37:01.948044+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-05-03T09:37:01.948166+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the donut-shop@1.0.0 start script.
2020-05-03T09:37:01.948288+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-05-03T09:37:01.958728+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-03T09:37:01.959061+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-05-03T09:37:01.959255+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-05-03T09_37_01_949Z-debug.log
2020-05-03T09:37:06.245883+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-05-03T09:37:06.150793+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-03T09:37:06.150819+00:00 app[web.1]: > donut-shop@1.0.0 start /app
2020-05-03T09:37:06.150819+00:00 app[web.1]: > next start -p $PORT
2020-05-03T09:37:06.150819+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-03T09:37:06.156507+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: next: not found
2020-05-03T09:37:06.159958+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-05-03T09:37:06.160245+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2020-05-03T09:37:06.160445+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2020-05-03T09:37:06.160667+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2020-05-03T09:37:06.161657+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! donut-shop@1.0.0 start: `next start -p $PORT`
2020-05-03T09:37:06.161787+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2020-05-03T09:37:06.161951+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-05-03T09:37:06.162087+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the donut-shop@1.0.0 start script.
2020-05-03T09:37:06.162208+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-05-03T09:37:06.169114+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-03T09:37:06.169269+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-05-03T09:37:06.169311+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-05-03T09_37_06_162Z-debug.log
2020-05-03T09:37:36.413398+00:00 app[api]: Release v8 created by user user@gmail.com
2020-05-03T09:37:36.413398+00:00 app[api]: Deploy fa8f626a by user user@gmail.com
2020-05-03T09:37:36.889585+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-03T09:37:39.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-05-03T09:37:41.156687+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-05-03T09:37:41.035745+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-03T09:37:41.035763+00:00 app[web.1]: > donut-shop@1.0.0 start /app
2020-05-03T09:37:41.035763+00:00 app[web.1]: > next start -p $PORT
2020-05-03T09:37:41.035764+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-03T09:37:41.089773+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: next: not found
2020-05-03T09:37:41.093458+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-05-03T09:37:41.093677+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2020-05-03T09:37:41.093814+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2020-05-03T09:37:41.093974+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2020-05-03T09:37:41.094896+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! donut-shop@1.0.0 start: `next start -p $PORT`
2020-05-03T09:37:41.094979+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2020-05-03T09:37:41.095109+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-05-03T09:37:41.095240+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the donut-shop@1.0.0 start script.
2020-05-03T09:37:41.095322+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-05-03T09:37:41.101385+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-03T09:37:41.101509+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-05-03T09:37:41.101588+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-05-03T09_37_41_096Z-debug.log
2020-05-03T09:37:47.263815+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=shielded-badlands-93212.herokuapp.com request_id=986c053b-b4eb-4f87-b1f2-265469dec1dd fwd="220.240.26.177" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-03T09:37:48.567909+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=shielded-badlands-93212.herokuapp.com request_id=3c65fd8b-0808-4746-91f9-406a4543c434 fwd="220.240.26.177" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "donut-shop",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p $PORT",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/core": "^10.0.27",
    "@emotion/styled": "^10.0.27",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.1.2",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "next": "latest",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-confetti": "^5.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "stripe": "^8.15.0"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0"
  }
}
```

any help to point in the right direct would be awesome legends!

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you were using a guide from 2017.

Might be better to use this guide from 2019 instead: https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-host-your-next-js-application-for-free-on-heroku-c6ba99ebb8b8

These frameworks do change fast, and makes older guides inadequate